# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.base' in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm having trouble using the pandas package on Spyder 4.2.1.

Currently using:

- MacOS Big Sur ver. 11.2
- Python 3.9
- Spyder 4.2.1
- Anaconda 2020.11

this is the code I'm trying to run:

```
import pandas as pd
```

This results in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.base' - along with a bunch of other errors.

Full error message:

```
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyc", line 14, in <module>

  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyc", line 10, in __load

  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.base'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyc", line 14, in <module>

  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyc", line 10, in __load

  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.missing

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module

KeyError: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyc", line 14, in <module>

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyc", line 10, in __load

  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.hashtable

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module

KeyError: 'pandas._libs.missing'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyc", line 14, in <module>

  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyc", line 10, in __load

  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module

KeyError: 'pandas._libs.hashtable'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/jack/Downloads/Introduction lab.py", line 78, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.tslibs.base

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/__init__.pyc", line 13, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module

KeyError: 'pandas._libs.interval'
```

What I've tried so far:

- Uninstalling / reinstalling Anaconda (I think I did it correctly?) so
  it's on my actual hard disk
- Uninstalling/reinstalling the actual pandas module through the terminal
- Restarting my Mac
- Updating Python to 3.9
- Updating Mac to Big Sur
- Using `import pandas._libs.tslibs.base` in my code
- Trying to just use `import` pandas`without`as pd`
- Going to the actual Anaconda files to try to find the error
- Using `pip uninstall` and `pip install` to try to reinstall the package
- Installing miniconda
- Using `conda install` to install the package
- **FACTORY RESETTING my Mac**

None of the above works. Considering literally factory resetting my Mac at this point (just did it, didn't work) because I need this to work for a class I'm taking and even the professor doesn't know how to fix this. For some reason nobody in my class seems to have this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of pandas is being installed? Usually this is because the C extensions didn't install properly. Have you verified the `pip` you're using is the one mapped to your virtualenv? You might be installing it correctly, and the imported pandas is not the same one as what's installed

Comment: Found the fix, without Anaconda, over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335316/pandas-importation-error-on-a-2019-macbook-pro-on-big-sur-newest-version-of-sp/66343588#66343588

Answer (score 1):

You should not use pip with Anaconda Python. You should use conda instead. So to install something use

```
conda install name_of_package
```

Try this and see if it works.

To check that conda is installed, which it should be, type conda -V

Then run conda update conda. You should be ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

When I installed Miniconda and manually imported Pandas, then reinstalled the conda kernel, it suddenly worked. I don't know exactly what I did to trigger it; if someone is more experienced they may be able to explain.