# Pandas importation error on a 2019 Macbook Pro on Big Sur + newest version of Spyder

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, macos-big-sur

I updated my 2019 Macbook Pro 15inch to Big Sur. I found that Spyder + Anaconda had a big lag, and the Spyder developers suggested just downloading the Spyder .dmg and use python through there.

But, every time I try to use pandas (I have multiple scripts that depend upon the package), I get this error:

```
runcell(0, '/Users/insertname/Documents/projectpath')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyc", line 14, in <module>

  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyc", line 10, in __load

  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.base'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyc", line 14, in <module>

  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyc", line 10, in __load

  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "pandas/_libs/missing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.missing

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module

KeyError: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyc", line 14, in <module>

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyc", line 10, in __load

  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.hashtable

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module

KeyError: 'pandas._libs.missing'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyc", line 14, in <module>

  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyc", line 10, in __load

  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1116, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module

KeyError: 'pandas._libs.hashtable'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/insertname/Documents/projectpath", line 12, in <module>
    import pandas

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module

  File "pandas/_libs/__init__.pyc", line 13, in <module>

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible

  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 261, in load_module

KeyError: 'pandas._libs.interval'
```

I'm only calling `import pandas` in the script, for now, for testing. I have totally scrubbed Anaconda from my computer, and have used `brew install` for the latest version of python (3.9.2) and have the latest Spyder version (4.2.1).

Spyder, along the bottom of the frame, says it's running python 3.9.1 - though I don't know if this has anything to do with it. I've tried `pip3` uninstalling pandas and reinstalling multiple times, cleaned my computer of Spyder & python (though not the python that comes with every Mac, 2.7 I believe) - and nothing gets me past the error above.

I do not want to go back to Anaconda (at least, until the lag is gone). I've tried everything in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020073/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslibs-base-in-anaconda) question - but I don't want to go the anaconda way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent two full days trying to find an answer. Here we go -

[image]

I don't know why it took a full day for the python interpreter to finally accept the input (I had to repoint the python package, u[sing the second answer on this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx)).

Then the console displayed a different version than the bottom of the Spyder IDE (3.9.1 vs 3.9.2).

Then I had to use `pip3 install spyder-kernels` - and boom. Good to go. Pandas error fixed.